# Dropdown list population from ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown

First of all, I know this question has been asked many, many times. I've read countless articles and Stack Overflow answers. I've tried to figure this problem out for four days and I think I need help if someone doesn't mind.

I have two databases. The employee database has a field called "DisplayName" -- the second database has a relationship with the first and they work together great. I'm able to call the two databases perfectly in another application.

You can see the in the picture [Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQkB1.png)
that I have a list of people. I want a dropdown below it that lists all display names in the database so employees can add themselves to the list. You'll see a dropdown in the image but it's not populated.

Seems simple. But geez. Part of a problem I'm having is my home controller already has a function to populate the list in the picture so I can't do another on that page. I've tried a lot of suggestions on a lot of sites. I get IEnumerable errors or display reference errors....

Here's my controller (again - it has nothing in it that helps the dropdown):

```
namespace SeatingChart.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var lists = db.BreakModels
                            .Include("Employee")
                            .Include("TimeEntered")
                            .Include("TimeCleared")
                            .Include("DisplayName")
                            .Select(a => new HomeIndexViewModels
                            {
                                Employee = a.Employee,
                                DisplayName = a.EmployeeModels.DisplayName,
                                TimeEntered = a.TimeEntered,
                                TimeCleared = a.TimeCleared.Value,
                                Id = a.EmployeeModels.Id,
                            });

            return View(lists);
        }
```

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<SeatingChart.Models.HomeIndexViewModels>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.Partial("_Header")

    <div class="container_lists">
        <div class="container_break col-md-8">
            <h5 style="text-align:center">Break List</h5>
            <table class="table-bordered col-lg-12">
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        if (item.TimeCleared == null)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &ensp;BV
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &ensp;@item.TimeEntered.ToString("HH:mm")
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </table>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="row site-spaced">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        @Html.DropDownList("DisplayName", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "---Dispatcher---" }), new { @class = "required " })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="site-control" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace SeatingChart.Models
{
        public class HomeIndexViewModels 
        {

        //Break Model
        public int BreakId { get; set; }
            public int Employee { get; set; }
            public DateTime TimeEntered { get; set; }
            public DateTime? TimeCleared { get; set; }

            //Employee Model
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string DisplayNames { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public bool NotActive { get; set; }
            public int Force { get; set; }

            public string EmployeeList { get; set; }


    }

}
```

I hope this is clear enough. I've tried so many different ways with so much code - the errors are different with everything I've tried.

Thanks in advance for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your viewmodel

```
public List<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }
```

Then you can populate this list with controller then in view just call it with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.Employees, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
```

Update - how to populate list. Should work (but not tested code).

```
    public List<SelectListItem> GetEmployeeForDropdown(List<HomeIndexViewModels> list)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> empList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        try
        {

                if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in list)
                    {
                        empList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.DisplayName, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    empList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No items", Value = string.Empty });
                }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exceptions here
        }

        return empList;
    }
```

Edit: Remember to use your model in view!

Comment: Thank you for the quick, patient reply. I'm a brand new baby programmer. I added code in the index controller below what I had. "            List<HomeIndexViewModels> Employees = new List<HomeIndexViewModels>();

            foreach (var user in db.EmployeeModels)
            {
                if (user.NotActive == false)
                {
                    Employees.Add(new HomeIndexViewModels());
                }
            }.... But I'm getting an error: Does Not Contain Definition.... for Model.Employees. How would you populate the Employee list? I'm doing that wrong as well.

Comment: @TylerJohnson Searh how to add to list

Comment: @JamesS I've searched every aspect of this for four days. I'm not going to post things just to hear "why don't you search for answers" if I hadn't spent days searching for answers. I've tried to populate that list. Everything I do and try after multiple tutorials and days of researching ends in errors. Of course I searched. I've spent days searching and doing tutorials. There's something wrong in my code that I'm not seeing. I'm trying to get help from people who can see what I'm not. But thanks for the suggestion.....

Comment: @TylerJohnson If it does not contain a definition for `Model.Employees`, it means you haven't defined it. In the constructor of the class OR in the controller method define the list by saying `model.Employees = new List<//Whatever the class is>`. However, from looking at the controller method, you haven't even defined a `model`